# Вывести количество посетителей с яндекс метрики за один день

Tags: php, api, яндекс-метрика

Подскажите пожалуйста как в запрос передать параметр (текущий день), чтобы получить количество уникальных посетителей сегодня. Сейчас запрос выглядит так (по умолчанию, там неделя):
   https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/data?metrics=ym:s:users&id=id&oauth_token=token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел решение - нужно в запрос добавить &date1=2018-05-19&date2=2018-05-19, это получить можно уже через date('Y-m-d') например